# Much Gap appear between last message and TextArea in Room

Tags: bug, chat

I am facing today a weird issue in Rooms Page Layouts. It was perfect till yesterday in my old browser (Google Chrome). Today I updated to new Version (Google Chrome 33.0.1750.154 m), From that I am facing this issue.

```
OS : Microsoft Windows 8
```

When I refresh the room page then everything appear perfect but When I do any event like click on upload/send or click on Shog/Shadow etc ... picture in Room then a gap appear between last message and TextArea. I draw the vertical line that showing a gap between them. This issue is in all rooms either it is on Meta Chat or any room which are on Stack Overflow.

[image]

When I refresh the page then it looks everything perfect.

[image]

All are default settings, no zoom, I have tried even Ctrl+0, not worked. and see in below screenshot fonts are normal.

[image]

Comment: No repro, same Chrome version Windows 8.1

Comment: I cleared the cache of it, still same problem persist and working perfectly in Internet Explorer

Comment: Any extension/plugin/user scripts installed?

Comment: @ShadowWizard No

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave some rest to my system and everything start to appear perfectly :) and this problems seems to have disappeared.